# How to set a limit to a list? python

Tags: python

I need the user to enter 4 school grades, and if he/she enters more than 4, a warning should appear saying 'not allowed to enter more than 4 school grades' at the moment I only know the basics and that's where it gets complicated... because I don't know how to place a limit to a list ....

```
notes = []
option = ''

while not option == '4':
    print('**********************')
    print('NOTES PORTAL')
    print('**********************')
    print('1) Add note')
    print('2) Edit note')
    print('3) Sort notes')
    print('4) Exit')
    print('**********************')

    option = input('Enter an option: ')

    if option == '1':
        if not notes:
            print('No notes registered')

            print('Enter the note you want to add')
            name = float(input())
            notes.append(name)
            if notes == 4:
                print('Cannot enter more than 4 notes')
                break
        else:
            print('Registered notes: ')
            for p in notes:
                print(f" {p}")

            print('Enter the note you want to add')
            name = float(input())
            notes.append(name)
            if notes == '5':
                print('No more than 4 notes can be entered')
                break
```

btw, I had to translate the code because it was written in Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The less than or greater than operator

Change your code in this line from this:

```py
if notes == 4:
   print('Cannot enter more than 4 notes')
   break
```

To this

```
if len(notes) > 4:
    print('Cannot enter more than 4 notes')
    break
```

The len() function gives you the size of the array, whereas the greater than operator means that everything that is greater than 4, will execute the code block inside of the If statement

Answer (score 1):

You check `len(notes)` and if it is `4`, then print the warning message and use `continue` to loop again to a new choice

```
while option != '4':
    print('**********************')
    print('NOTES PORTAL')
    print('**********************')
    print('1) Add note\n2) Edit note\n3) Sort notes\n4) Exit')
    print('**********************')

    option = input('Enter an option: ')
    if option == '1':
        if not notes:
            print('No notes registered')
        else:
            print('Registered notes: ')
            for p in notes:
                print(f" {p}")

            if len(notes) == 4:
                print('No more than 4 notes can be entered')
                continue

        name = float(input('Enter the note you want to add: '))
        notes.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading your code and explanation, you should check the length of notes with `len(notes)`

Comment: Take a look at [Pedro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67744306/3025856) (submitted around the same time as yours) for a good example of how to explain code to help readers understand _why_ you're proposing the change, and not just _what_ to change.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "limit" the amount of elements that a list can hold, you can use an if condition when appending another element to make sure that there is not already 4 in the list.

With your code, it seems like you were trying to do this with

```
if notes == 4:
```

and...

```
if notes == 5:
```

However, this doesn't work because you are comparing the integer value of 4 or 5 with the value of a list. To make this work, you can use the len() function built into Python that can get the current length or number of elements in a list. To do this, you can use the code below.

```
if len(notes) != 4:
    notes.append(name)
else:
    print("No more notes can be added!")
```

This will make sure that there are not 4 notes in the current list both appending a new one. Hopefully this answers your question.